# Power BI（DAX関数）で、ExcelのCOUNTIF関数と同等の結果を得られる列を追加したい

Tags: excel, azure, powerbi

#### 実現したいこと

Power BIにて、あるセルの値が、同一列内にいくつあるかカウントした結果を格納する列を追加したいと思っています。
添付のExcelの画像を例に説明させていただきます。

[image: Excelでの実現例]

Power BI上では、テーブル上にA列～D列のみ存在しているものとします。
E列：「年月日」が同一な行数をカウントした結果
F列：「年月日」が同一で、かつ「時」も同一な行数をカウントした結果
となるよう、E列およびF列をそれぞれ追加したいです。
添付の画像はそのようなE列、F列を追加したものです。
より具体的には、ExcelであればE2セルは、

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)
```

F2セルは、

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)
```

で実現できる値になります。
Power BI上で同等の列追加ができずに困っています。

FILTER関数を使おうにも、B列について、B2セルの値と一致する行のみ表示する、
といった内容の表現方法がわかりません。
テーブルを新たに作る等の工夫も必要になるのでしょうか？

解決方法をご存知の方はご回答いただけますと幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Power BIのcountrows関数とfilter関数の併用でできませんか？